# how hide temporary list items and after reappear toggle button

Tags: javascript, list, hide

how hide temporary list items and after reappear toggle button? when there is a hidden item , this can be found with it's id?

```js
function action(x) {
    var parag = document.getElementById("li" + x);
    if(parag.style.visibility = "hidden"){
        parag.style.visibility = "visible";
    }else{
        parag.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

either use the below do not work?

```html
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function action(x){ 
var parag=document.getElementById("li"+x); 
    if(parag.style.display=="none"){ 
        parag.style.display="block"; 
    }else{ 
        parag.style.display="none"; 
    } 
} 

</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul> 
     <li id="li1">Item1</li>
     <li id="li2">Item2</li>
     <li id="li3">Item3</li>
</ul>
<form name="myform"><input type="button" onclick="alert(document.myform.select.value);action(document.myform.select.value)" value="show/hide"/><label>
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</label></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the first code:

```
if(parag.style.visibility="hidden"){
```

should be

```
if(parag.style.visibility=="hidden"){
```

, otherwise the `parag.style.visibility` will **always** be set to `hidden` and the expression will **always** evaluate to `true`.